# The server respond me with GNU TSL error

Tags: linux, ftp

I tried to connect to a server of one company where I am supposed to access their database, but the server replays me with the following error message.

```
Fout:   GnuTLS-fout -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
Fout:   Kan niet verbinden met server
```

I have all the login credentials, what do you think the problem can be?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems you are using implicit TLS instead of explicit TLS.

Look at [FTP_over_TLS: Explicit vs Implicit FTPS](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FTP_over_TLS#Explicit_vs_Implicit_FTPS):

> FTPS (FTP over TLS) is served up in two incompatible modes. If using
>   explicit FTPS, the client connects to the normal FTP port and
>   explicitly switches into secure (TLS) mode with "AUTH TLS", whereas
>   implicit FTPS is an older style service that assumes TLS mode right
>   from the start of the connection (and normally listens on TCP port
>   990, rather than 21). In a FileZilla client this means prefixing the
>   host with "FTPES://" to connect an "explicit" FTPS server, or
>   "FTPS://" for the legacy "implicit" server (for which you will likely
>   also need to set the port to 990).

At he same page you can find [how to setup client](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FTP_over_TLS#Client_Setup):

> For a client to connect to a server using TLS, then the host for that
>   connection needs to be set to FTPS. In FileZilla client this means
>   prefixing the host with "FTPES://" for "explicit" FTPS, or "FTPS://"
>   for the legacy "implicit" FTPS.